# Uploading to anonfiles API with curl in python

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I want to upload to [anonfiles](https://anonfiles.com) using the requests module. Code runs but the files don't appear on the website. Here's my code so far:

```
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('file.txt', open('file.txt', 'rb')),
}
requests = requests.post('https://api.anonfiles.com/upload/?token=mytoken', files=files)
```

Any ideas as to what could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you get in `response`? Maybe there is message which explains problem. Maybe you used wrong parameters or wrong token.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You use wrong URL - it has to be without `/` at the end.

```
https://api.anonfiles.com/upload
```

And it seems it works also without `token`

```
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('file.txt', open('file.txt', 'rb')),
}

url = 'https://api.anonfiles.com/upload'
response = requests.post(url, files=files)

data = response.json()

print(data['data']['file']['url']['short'])
```

---

Doc: [API](https://anonfiles.com/docs/api)

Comment: Removing the / made it work. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @0xStefanos you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it (but for this you may need bigger `reputation score`)

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is the PyPI library [anonfile](https://github.com/nstrydom2/anonfile-api), which provides an easy-to-use interface for the [anonfiles.com](https://anonfiles.com)'s API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).